# the index() function returns null even if the value is present

Tags: sass

I try to get the index of a value in a map, but it returns null. which is strange since I know the key/value is in the map.

And whats even stranger is that it works fine when using other values than the last one.

Code:

```
index(($mediaSizesMap), ($size $s))
```

> $size = xl, $s = 1200px

Map:

```
$mediaSizesMap: (xs: 0, sm: 576px, md: 768px, lg: 992px, xl: 1200px);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mediaSizesMap: (xs: 0, sm: 576px, md: 768px, lg: 992px, xl: 1200px);

$size: xl;
$s: 1200px;

div {
  content: index($mediaSizesMap, ($size $s));
}
```

Output:

```
div {
  content: 5;
}
```